# Combine Multiple Sheets to One Dynamic Master

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to combine multiple tabs into one master sheet and have it update when new tabs are added. This is the script I have so far but it relsults in an error. I think it may be an issue with the let array / filter part?

```
function combineData() {
   // ={filter({'November ''22'!A3:W,"November '22 - Row "&ROW('November ''22'!A3:A)},'November ''22'!A3:A<>""); 
// filter({'December ''22'!A3:W,"December '22 - Row "&ROW('December ''22'!A3:A)},'December ''22'!A3:A<>"");
// filter({'January ''23'!A3:W,"January '23 - Row "&ROW('January ''23'!A3:A)},'January ''23'!A3:A<>"");
// filter({'February ''23'!A3:W,"February '23 - Row "&ROW('February ''23'!A3:A)},'February ''23'!A3:A<>"");
// filter({'March ''23'!A3:W,"March '23 - Row "&ROW('March ''23'!A3:A)},'March ''23'!A3:A<>"")}

//{filter({'November ''22'!A3:W,"November '22 - Row "&ROW('November ''22'!A3:A)},'November ''22'!A3:A<>"")

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ignoreSheets = ["Lease Rentals 2022","Combined data","Pivot Table 1","Master","October '22","Nov '21 Slate Beds","Nov '21 Slate Beds - Sales","Nov '21 Slate Beds - Refunds","Nov '21 Slate Beds - Comparison"];

const allSheets = ss.getSheets();

const filteredListOfSheets = allSheets.filter(s =>ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1 );


let formulaArray = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}'!A3:W,"${s.getSheetName()} - Row "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!A3:A)},'${s.getSheetName()}'!A3:A<>"")`);


let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";") + "}";

//console.log(formulaText);
ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange("A2").setFormula(formulaText);

}
```

Expected a combined master sheet using filter functions but error occurs instead.

Comment: Hello! Try changing "let" with "var"

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve]: Remove the uncesary code as the commented lines as they they provide any useful information, add a brief description of the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, including the sheet names, add the textual error message, the expected formula to be written to the spreadsheet. Also consider to add console.log statements to print to the execution logs the values of `formulaArray`and `formulaText` and add those logs as text into the question.